# One thread controlling many others

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have an application that waits for clients to connect. Each time a client connects, a new frame gets created (with the new socket file descriptor). I know how many clients will connect, after I reach that number I just run pthread_join in a for loop.

My problem is that I would like the main thread to control all the other threads. My goal is to have each thread send the same message back to the client, at the same time, and only once. There are multiple messages a thread can send.

My current thinking is to define a list of command, as follows:

```
char *commands[] = {
                (char*) "TERMINATE\0",
                .... };
```

And then specify a command number that represents which command to use in that char* array. All threads will do something like

```
write(sockfd, buffer[commandNumber], length[commandNumber]);
```

I thought about waiting on a condition variable, but I see two problems:

1) I want to make sure that each thread, although synchronized, execute the command only once.

2) The main thread that initiates the command has to know when all those threads is done executing the command.

Only way I see to execute 2) is to keep track of a counter (with mutexes), and when each thread executes the command, it can increase that counter. I am not sure I will be able to avoid a thread from running the command twice.

What is the best possible way please to coordinate multiple threads to execute a single action at once; and also be able to know when that action has finished executing for every thread please?

Comment: Does the main thread accept the client connections, and then hand them off (in a frame object) to the worker threads?

Comment: Yes, accept() executes, then I call pthread_create with the new socket as a parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a [barrier](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html) to gate the operation.

### Synchronizing the send

The main thread initializes a barrier named "Ready" to N+1.  Then it begins accept()ing N client connections, spawning a worker thread for each.  The new worker threads immediately wait on barrier "Ready".

After spawning the Nth (and last) worker, the main thread sets the desired command (perhaps using a global `commandNumber`).  Then the main thread waits on barrier "Ready".  As soon as all workers and the main thread have arrived (reaching the barrier's limit of N+1), all threads are released, knowing that they are *ready* to issue their command immediately.

(A common alternate approach is to use a predicate and condition variable rather than a barrier.  For example, the main thread might spawn the Nth worker and then cond_broadcast() that it has set a flag `ready = 1`.  **This approach is flawed.**  The main thread cannot know that the Nth worker — or, indeed, any of the workers — are yet waiting on that condition.  The barrier solves this problem.)

### Indicating completion

Another N+1 barrier, "AllDone", could be used to indicate that the workers are all done.  A semaphore initialized to -N and posted by workers would do the same.  Having the workers close() their connections and the main thread select()ing or poll()ing connections would convey the same information, too.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! For the last part, the connection stays open, as there may be a new command (for example stopping the first command in a start/stop model, just one example). Basically, the model is that once those N clients exist, I can keep using all the threads until the main threads decide it's time to finish. I didn't know about Barriers. This is perfect, thank you!

Comment: I assume I can use two barriers, one being the current command, and the next one being the next command.

Comment: @user1777907, it may be worth it for you to implement a cyclic barrier that can be used over and over by N+1 parties.  Java has a famous one, and the [perl implementation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Thread-Barrier/) is fairly easy to follow.

Comment: I have one issue (I think). Initially I wait for all processes to be up (1), then a command is ready to be executed (2), then all processes run the command and finishes (3), then (2), then (3),... until (2) tells the thread to terminate. Your explanation helped me figure out when all threads are up and when they are done. How can X threads know when the main thread tells them a command is ready please?

Comment: I think (1) is actually the same as (2) and maybe 2 barriers should suffice. Do you mind if I post my code soon please? I'd love to have your opinion on it if it does not bother you.

Comment: @user1777907, that would be suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Code is available here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25720/uses-of-barriers-for-one-main-thread-controlling-n-threads. It seems to work fine but doesn't procude the expected result for the 3rd comment. It could be something else in my code (not the barrier code showed, not sure yet). Thanks a lot pilcrow. I look forward for your comments!